# Segmentation violation when using *C.uchar

Tags: c, xml, go, libxml2

I need to deal with C code inside Go. [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/index.html) and [github.com/jbowtie/gokogiri/xml](https://github.com/jbowtie/gokogiri) are used to generate XML files. However, the encoding doesn't appear in the final document, so I explicitly set the encoding (`docPtr.encoding = enc`):

```
func xmlSaveTree(docPtr *C.xmlDoc, encoding []byte, options int, outputBuffer []byte) ([]byte, int) {
    var (
        cEncoding *C.char
    )

    if len(encoding) > 0 {
        enc := cbuf(encoding)
        docPtr.encoding = enc
        defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(enc))

        cEncoding = C.CString(string(encoding))
        defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cEncoding))
    }

    wbufferMutex.Lock()
    defer wbufferMutex.Unlock()
    if outputBuffer == nil {
        outputBuffer = make([]byte, 0)
    }
    wbuffer = &WriteBuffer{Buffer: outputBuffer}

    ret := int(C.MY_xmlSaveDoc(docPtr, cEncoding, C.int(options)))
    if ret < 0 {
        panic("output error in xml node serialization: " + strconv.Itoa(ret))
    }
    b, o := wbuffer.Buffer, wbuffer.Offset
    wbuffer = nil

    return b, o
}

func cbuf(buf []byte) *C.uchar {
    var bufptr *byte
    if cap(buf) > 0 {
        bufptr = &(buf[:1][0])
    }
    return (*C.uchar)(bufptr)
}
```

Using this gives me a segmentation violation:

> fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution [signal
> SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x7f0519e25c71]
>
> runtime stack: runtime.throw(0x6bed23, 0x2a)
> /home/usr/.go/src/runtime/panic.go:1116 +0x72 runtime.sigpanic()
> /home/usr/.go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:704 +0x4ac
>
> goroutine 39 [syscall]: runtime.cgocall(0x63c840, 0xc000050b48, 0x0)
> /home/usr/.go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:133 +0x5b fp=0xc000050b18 sp=0xc000050ae0 pc=0x40859b
> gitlab.com/company/xmlmix/document/internal._Cfunc_free(0xa64258)
> _cgo_gotypes.go:265 +0x45 fp=0xc000050b48 sp=0xc000050b18 pc=0x57eb05
> gitlab.com/company/xmlmix/document/internal.xmlSaveTree.func1.1()
> /mnt/Entwicklung/project/xmlmix/document/internal/marshal.go:82
> +0x53 fp=0xc000050b80 sp=0xc000050b48 pc=0x57fa33 gitlab.com/company/xmlmix/document/internal.xmlSaveTree(0x27ae130,
> 0xa64258, 0x5, 0x5, 0x23, 0xaa7408, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0001ac000, 0x2534,
> ...)
> /mnt/project/xmlmix/document/internal/marshal.go:102
> +0x2b0 fp=0xc000050c18 sp=0xc000050b80 pc=0x57f710 gitlab.com/company/xmlmix/document/internal.XMLSaveDoc(0x701920,
> 0xc0000fa990, 0x23, 0xa64258, 0x5, 0x5, 0xe, 0xf, 0xc000050d48,
> 0x555855, ...)
> /mnt/project/xmlmix/document/internal/marshal.go:62
> +0xe7 fp=0xc000050c90 sp=0xc000050c18 pc=0x57f3c7 gitlab.com/company/xmlmix/document.MarshalIndent(0xc0000a68b8, 0x0,
> 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
> /mnt/project/xmlmix/document/marshal.go:50 +0x105 fp=0xc000050d58 sp=0xc000050c90 pc=0x5d92c5

Comment: `defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(enc))` is an attempt to call C's `free()` on a memory block allocated by Go—the backing array of `encoding []byte`. The dance around `cap()` in the `cbuf` function is also beyond my understanding. Still, the error comes from the call at `xmlmix/document/internal/marshal.go:82` which tries to call C's `free` on some memory it should have not. You need to trace the call chain form `C.MY_xmlSaveDoc` to see why it happens.

Comment: I'd start small and first cook all parameters to that call using `cgo` functions which are guaranteed to produce C-allocated data (forget about memory leaks just yet) and then would gradually move the code to operate with Go memory — watching each step carefully until it blows up, so that you know what addition is the culprit.

Comment: You may also want to look at the docs of the Gokogiri routines you are calling to make sure that you are using them as documented.  For example, they may say something about required characteristics of the arguments or about restrictions on how you may use return values.  It would also be worth your while to try to produce a [mre].  That will help you validate your usage against the docs, it might help you find a workaround, it might help us help you, and if you've discovered a bug in Gokogiri then it will be a good basis for a bug report.